# Can't get twilio to show 'from' data but it will show 'to' data

Tags: python, flask, twilio, twilio-api

I have set up a Twilio app that I want to send updates to people, but I don't want to respond to individual text. I just want them to call if there is a question. I have everything working but I want to show incoming text if one gets sent, just to make sure I don't miss a question. I am using python/flask. I have my template set up and I can get it to show me all my messages, and even who the message went to, but I can't get it to show who the message was from.

```
{% for msg in msgs %}
    {% if msg.direction == 'inbound' %}
        <p> {{ msg.from }} : {{ msg.body }} </p>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This will show all my messages but won't show anything else. If I change it to {{ msg.to }} it will show who the message is to. I have also tried to request in my app.

```
numbs = request.form["From"]
```

And then iterate over it in my template using a for loop, but no such luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `from_` instead of `from` since `from` is a keyword in python used for imports.

Comment: well does the `msg` object have a `_from` attribute? What does it look like when you `print(msg)` or `print(msg.__dict__)` ?

Comment: It appears that {{ msg.from_ }} is what works. I can't seem to find this in the Twilio docs anywhere, but your answer helped me get there!

Comment: Ahh that makes sense, cool. I updated my answer to reflect this, in case someone else has the same problem in the future